# Using libraries in my namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I have several libraries inside my project, made in `namespace`. When I need to use one of them inside my controller `(MVC)` I'm including a `require` and using this library which is in the same namespace as well. I was wondering if I can join the namespaces so I do not need this require inside the controller every time. My `autoload` is loaded in another file, then call the `controller` to continue the rule.

Actual controller

```
namespace application\controller\rule;

use application\controller\database;
use application\model\object as object;

require '/xxx/xxx/autoloadLibary1.php';
require '/xxx/xxx/autoloadLibary2.php';
require '/xxx/xxx/autoloadLibary3.php';
require '/xxx/xxx/autoloadLibary4.php';

class MyClass {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I may not have understood you fully but I think you want to use

`require '/xxx/xxx/autoloadLibary1.php';` as `use application\xxx\xxx;`

so for this you have to use composer or an alternative that I always use instead of *composer*, basically use [this](https://github.com/animesh1969/PackageLoader) link to download psr-4/psr-0 autoloader safer way than composer, copy file composer-file-loader-master/PackageLoader.php to your project.

use this

```
include __DIR__ . '/includes/PackageLoader.php';
$packageLoader = new PackageLoader\PackageLoader();
$packageLoader->load( __DIR__ . '/includes' );//change where your composer.json file located
```

use this psr-4 autoloading to locate more than two locations in single namespace

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Namespace\\": [
            "./xxx/xxx/",
            "./another-location"
        ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if you use this statement:

```
use application\controller\database;
use application\model\object as object;

use application\xxx\xxx\autoloadLibary1;
use application\xxx\xxx\autoloadLibary2;
use application\xxx\xxx\autoloadLibary3;
use application\xxx\xxx\autoloadLibary4;
```

it sould work well! Happy Coding! If it helps be sure to support me be by accepting.

Comment: Why would you say your package loader library is safer than composer?

Comment: It does not spoil any code underneath. While if anybody knows just a little bit of programming they can notice what things are autoloaded because it does only require statement inside the vendor/autoload.php. While in other hand package loader uses basic php structure(like api/ its really a api haha) So its better to use it because it cannot spoil directly by accessing the php files, its protected... Last word, I'm recommend to make json file from composer but use it with package loader